# getting different location than current location on google map.android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, location

I am trying to access my current location as soon as the map loads but I am getting different location than my current location. What can be the reason?? Please help..

ChooseFromMapActivity

public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

```
public static String ShopLat;
public static String ShopPlaceId;
public static String ShopLong;
// Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
private TextView markerText;
private LatLng center;
private LinearLayout markerLayout;
private Geocoder geocoder;
private List<Address> addresses;
private TextView Address;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private GPSTracker gps;
private LatLng curentpoint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
        markerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
        markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
            // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        /*
         * Set the update interval
         */
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
            mUpdatesRequested = false;

        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
         * callbacks.
         */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

private void stupMap() {
    try {

        mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,
                        new LocationListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                markerText.setText("Location received: "
                                        + location.toString());

                            }
                        });

        Log.e("Reached", "here");

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {

                if (status.isSuccess()) {

                    Log.e("Result", "success");

                } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                    // Google provides a way to fix the issue
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,
                                100);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        gps = new GPSTracker(ChooseFromMapActivity.this);

        gps.canGetLocation();

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(curentpoint).zoom(17f).tilt(70).build();

        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(curentpoint));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        // Clears all the existing markers
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                curentpoint=mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                mGoogleMap.clear();

                try {
                    new GetLocationAsync(curentpoint.latitude,curentpoint.longitude)
                            .execute();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stupMap();

}

private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // boolean duplicateResponse;
    double x, y;
    StringBuilder str;

    public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        x = latitude;
        y = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
            str = new StringBuilder();
            if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

                if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(localityString + "");
                    str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                    str.append(zipcode + "");
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

GPSTracker

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
private final FragmentActivity mActivity;

// flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

// The minimum distance to change updates in metters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10
// metters

// The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(FragmentActivity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mActivity
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : Location",
                "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }

    return location;
}

public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 */

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        locationManager = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 */
public void showSettingsAlert() {

    if (mActivity == null || mActivity.isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    mActivity);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog
                    .setMessage("Your GPS is disabled, Enable GPS in settings or continue with approximate location");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            mActivity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {

                            // UserSerch doSerch = new UserSerch();
                            // doSerch.doserchOn();
                            // dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.create().show();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
 *
 * @return null or List<Address>
 */
public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
    if (location != null) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);
            return addresses;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder",
                    e);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Try to get AddressLine
 *
 * @return null or addressLine
 */
public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

        return addressLine;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Locality
 *
 * @return null or locality
 */
public String getLocality(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        return locality;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Postal Code
 *
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

        return postalCode;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get CountryName
 *
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getCountryName(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String countryName = address.getCountryName();

        return countryName;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    showSettingsAlert();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.siddhi.go_jek" >


<uses-permission android:name="com.example.siddhi.mapdmo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<permission
    android:name="com.example.siddhi.mapdmo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDjQ6onUW2O34wjnrYqsWht48FGGOPVZWI" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GoSend"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.siddhi.go_jek.MainActivity" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PickLocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pick_location"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseFromMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_from_map"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am getting the location at Dalvik when the map loads but currently I am at mumbai so map should showmy location at mumbai.
Whats going wrong?? Can anyone help please??

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean Dalvik in Iceland ?
Cause i had the same problem, Location was 59;03 instead of 03;59

Maybe try

```
    x = longitude;
    y = latitude;
```

Add some trace during execution with *Log.e* and see where the wrong Location comes from :)

Comment: Cause i cant remember all this code ^^'  Try some "Log.e" every time there is a Location used, and see where the wrong Location comes from

Comment: ...Its already in code..    public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }                                                                                                        @Me Good Guy

Comment: i know... im saying to switch x and y. i cant find an error in all this code... Try some Log.e everywhere and u will find where excatly the error is from, then i could help

Comment: no. Switching dose not help.. Where all should I add log.e?? I am new to android please can you explain in detail?? How did you solved your problem?? @Me Good Guy

Comment: Everytime in the code there is a latitude or a longitude. Use "Log.e("coordinates used ==> ", "("+latitude+":"+longitude+")" );". Then run your application and u will see red lines in the Android Monitor

Comment: hey I am getting correct location on my phone. Now I checked on my phone but it was showing dalvik on avd....